# Outlook - How to Prefix original email contents with some character while replying to that email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In Microsoft Outlook-2007, when I reply to a message, with my replies embedded within the Original Email, I would like to make the content of the original email preceded with some character, say ' >>'  as marker or separator. Is there any Outlook setting which will do it automatically.

Thank You.

-Ajit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DMA57361: This options prefixes all the original message with a Vertical Bar(Line) It did not take the character which i entered to prefix each line of the original message with. But I can work around by another setting present there. I can tick the box - "Mark my comments with" and enter the character i want. This character will be be prefixed to my embedded replies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is:

- Open **Tools** -> **Options** from the menu bar to access the **Options Window**.
- Under the **Preferences** tab select the **Email Options** button.
- There's a section titled **On replies and forwards**, which contains the options you need.
  Specifically, one of the options is *Prefix each line of the original message*, and you can also set the character to be used for the prefix.

I'm not 100% sure but I believe these are not always strictly adhered to if you are using HTML format (or replying to an HTML format message) instead of plain text.

Comment: This options prefixes all the original message with a Vertical Bar(Line) It did not take the character which i entered to prefix each line of the original message with.

Comment: @Golden - are your messages plain text or HTML? As mentioned I think Outlook ignores *some* of these options for HTML messages.

Comment: @DMA57361 I have the same issue. I think the messages are in HTML.  I'll put up a new question for HTML messages.

Comment: @goldenmean - I think it is doing what you asked for, and if you look at as plain text you'll see that, but just showing you a "prettier" output.

Comment: Hmm, my comment appears to be dated, based on Outlook 2003 and earlier behavior. See http://www.msoutlook.info/question/400