# Outlook - Prefix Reply With Character (HTML e-mails, too)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

This question:

> [Outlook - How to Prefix original email contents with some character while replying to that email](https://superuser.com/questions/201850/outlook-how-to-prefix-original-email-contents-with-some-character-while-replyi)

is  very similar to mine, and it was addressed with the less-than-helpful

> I'm not 100% sure but I believe these are not always strictly adhered to if you are using HTML format (or replying to an HTML format message) instead of plain text.

Currently, when I reply, outlook prefixes the original with a vertical bar (it even shows a little picture in the options pane).  I would like > signs because they're editable.  Perhaps it would be sufficient to just be able to break the vertical bar so I can type between lines of the original.

I'm using Outlook 2007 (12.0.6607.1000), Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to change the character that prefixes the included original text in an HTML email - only in non-HTML formats.  Choosing "include original message text" in the options instead of "prefix each line of the original message" also removes the vertical line prefix from HTML emails.

However, you CAN type in between lines (i.e. insert comments) in the original text.  The vertical line that denotes the original text remains even on your inserted text.