# Change plaintext reply prefix

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

When you reply to a plaintext email in Outlook (2013, though same issue with 2010), it always prefixes the original message with something like the following:

```
> -----Original Message-----
> From: Doe, John
> Sent: Friday, July 31, 2015 1:23 PM
> To: Soap, Joe
> Subject: RE: My awesome email
```

The rest of the message follows, prefixed with `>` characters ([as I have configured](https://superuser.com/a/201856/426664)). I see some other clients include a different prefix, like this:

```
2015-07-31 13:23, John Doe:
```

Or

```
On 7/31/15 1:23 PM, John Doe wrote:
```

To me, these are far more readable (and significantly less space consuming). Is this something that people can configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't something that can be configured.

As you pointed out, you can modify the prefix character (the ">") by going to options > Mail > Replies & Forwards, but changing the format of the original headers can't be done from Outlook.

Most likely you will find that the users with the better mail header will be running a different mail client (iMail, Thunderbird, various webmail clients, phones, etc).

Sorry, this isn't what you wanted to hear - but hopefully it answers your question.